# Merge two json objects in postgresql views/functions

Tags: postgresql, psql, sql-view, postgresql-9.5, postgresql-json

I have following 3 tables in postgress ...

```
Employee (employee_id, ...)
Address (address_id, owner_id, ...)
Address_Component (address_id, key, value)
```

while address component has data like ...

```
| 123 | province     | Toronto      |
| 123 | country      | Canada       |
| 123 | addressLine1 | some address |
```

Employee can have multiple addresses, and each address is associated with one address component.

I want to have address as json and address_component as another json embedded inside address object.

```
select emp.employee_id,
    array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(adr))) as address,
    json_object(array_agg(adrcomp.key), array_agg(adrcomp.value)) as address_component
   FROM employee emp
   LEFT JOIN address adr ON adr.owner_id = emp.employee_id
   LEFT JOIN address_component adrcomp ON adr.address_id = adrcomp.address_id
   WHERE employee_id = 'a6f49ab5-1769-4953-9b0e-6c12754d33c7'
   GROUP BY emp.employee_id
```

With this I am able to correctly get array of addresses as json, while I temporary have address component as separate result. Could you help me merge this address_component json into individual element of address json array, to have output like below?

```
[{ address_id:"123", owner_id: "E1", address_component: {province:"", "country":"", addressLine1:""} }, { ... }]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do everything on the same level, since you are aggregating twice. You'll need to create the `address_component` from its own subquery:

```
SELECT emp.employee_id,
       jsonb_agg((
         SELECT a FROM (
           SELECT adr.address_id, adr.owner_id,
                  (SELECT json_object_agg(key, value)
                   FROM address_component 
                   WHERE address_id = adr.address_id) AS address_component) a))
FROM employee emp
LEFT JOIN address adr ON adr.owner_id = emp.employee_id
WHERE employee_id = 'a6f49ab5-1769-4953-9b0e-6c12754d33c7'
GROUP BY emp.employee_id
```